# Insert unicode symbol ⋕ (U+22D5), equal and parallel into my maths equations

Tags: unicode-math

I would like to use the unicode symbol ⋕ (U+22D5), but I have no idea how to go about it.[image: an image of ⋕]

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

$\overline{KF}$ is also equal and $\parallel$ to $\overline{ML}$

\end{document}
```

I cannot find it in any list of symbols for latex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just superimpose `\parallel` to `=`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\eqparallel}{\mathrel{\vphantom{\parallel}\mathpalette\eqparallel@\relax}}
\newcommand{\eqparallel@}[2]{%
  \ooalign{\hidewidth$\m@th#1\parallel$\hidewidth\cr$\m@th#1=$\cr}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$X\eqparallel Y_{\eqparallel}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The (nonsense) subscript just shows that the symbol correctly changes size in the various math styles.

Answer (score 6):

In `unicode-math` this symbol can either be entered directly or using `\equalparallel`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{document}
\[
  A \equalparallel B
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't compile for me. I must have a conflict in my preamble. Ill try and see if its something I don't need.

Comment: Since the question is tagged `unicode-math` I assumed that you're already using it, if not the most likely issue is that you need LuaLaTeX for it to work (or XeLaTeX, but why would anyone use that these days?)